# List in Customer Paramater Report not being Refreshed

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

My customer parameter list not being refreshed after I save and reopen Crystal Report.

I created a report in 2011 and when I run the report, the customer paramameter comes up with a list of customers to choose from. When I save and reopen it, the list seems to disappear.

Any ideas how to fix this ? Someone mentioned ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh but you can not set this anywhere in Crystal Reports 2011.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what are you trying to perform. Normally when you close the report and reopen it to view the parameter you need to compulsory refresh the report.

Comment: I am trying to save a report the business objects enterprise store and then reopen the report from there again using crystal. When I do so, the customer parameter drop down list used to select customer is empty and the only way to get the information back is to create the parameter again .

Comment: When you veiw the saved report on BO at the top of the window you have two options "Group Tree" and "Parameters",May be you have ignored "Parameters"... Wierd guess try again to view and check parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has disappeared . Not sure what the root cause was . Vary strange.